# Converting input string to hex does not produce correct size

Tags: c, string, memory, hex, shared

I am trying to convert input string from pipe to hexadecimal, the input is 8KB but converted hex is just 6KB, I print out normal input and the correct lines are coming. I also try to write that hex string to shared memory, maybe my problem is the memory pointer but I'm not sure.

But, it prints out hex correctly for small inputs, I am stuck.

String to hex:

```
void stringtohex(char *input, char *output) {
    int loop;
    int i; 

    i = 0;
    loop = 0;

    while (input[loop] != '\0') {
        sprintf((char*)(output + i), "%02X", input[loop]);
        loop += 1;
        i += 2;
    }
    //insert NULL at the end of the output string
    output[i++] = '\0';
}
```

Reading part:

```
    int num;
    char s[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while ((num = read(fd, s, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {     
        //fprintf(stderr, "input: \n%s\n", s);
        int len = strlen(s);
        char hex[(len * 2) + 1];
        stringtohex(s, hex);
        sprintf(ptr_child_2, "%s", hex);
        ptr_child_2 += strlen(hex);
    }
```

here `ptr` is a `void *` mapped to shared memory.

Comment: Are you sure `s` is `'\0'` terminated?

Comment: I am not actually

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Can you give an example of file contents?

Answer (score 1):

Using `read` to read data into `s` and then treat `s` as if it is a string (e.g. you are calling `strlen(s);`) is wrong. The function `read` have no knowledge of strings. It simply tries to read `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes. So you may get less than a string or multiple strings into `s` in a single `read` but it's unlikely that you'll get exactly one string (as your code assumes).

Also notice that you never use `num` in your code. That's also strange as `num` holds the number of bytes that were actually stored in `s`. Consider using `num` to control the number of bytes to convert.

Or if you really want to operate on strings, take a look at `fgets` instead.

BTW: Check what `sprintf` returns... you'll find it useful ;-)

BTW: You could also consider `strcat` instead of `sprintf`

The correct solution may depend on the input data but something like this:

```
char* stringtohex(char* input, char* output, int num)
{
    int loop=0;

    while(loop < num)
    {
        sprintf(output, "%02X", input[loop]);
        loop+=1;
        output += 2;
    }

    //insert NULL at the end of the output string
    *output = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

Reading part **note:** `ptr_child_2` must point to an empty string to start with:

```
        char RESULT[SOME_SUFFICIENT_BIG_NUMBER] = ""; // Or dynamic allocation  
        char* ptr_child_2 = RESULT;
        int num;
        char s[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while((num = read(fd, s, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {     
            ptr_child_2 = stringtohex(s, ptr_child_2, num);
        }
        printf("%s\n", RESULT);
```

Comment: I print out ptr, hex but they both look fine. However, after increasing ptr I guess something is lost.

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ Start by printing `num` and `len`. Are they equal? I assume they ain't.

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ How does your input look? Just **one long string** or multiple strings? What is the value of `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: buffer size is 64 KB, input file includes 4 paragraphs, only text. output is empty

Comment: num = len and strlen(hex) is double of len

Comment: it worked fine at the first time, I copied input file and paste to the bottom of file. basically increase the size to its double. input is 13 KB output is 11KB. Maybe I should append end of string when while loop is over?

Comment: this is the ptr: void *ptr_child_2 = mmap(0,MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_child_2, 0);

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ aha... `mmap` ... you should have posted that !! Then it's probably a bad idea to change `ptr_child_2`!! Anyway - to start with drop the `mmap` and use a simply char array as destination - like in my example. Then you'll probably see that this code works. After that you can solve the `mmap` problem

Comment: what could be the problem then, yeah your way works

Comment: `sprintf(output, "%02X", input[loop]);` is a problem when `input[loop] < 0` -possible UB.  Recommend using `unsigned char`.

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ Well, we can't tell you what the problem is when you don't post the relevant code!! Edit your question to include the relevant parts - best if you can post a complete program